# How can I multiply a row of a data frame by a value (funds) and the result use it to multiply the following row and so on?

Tags: r, dataframe, row, quantmod, portfolio

[TABLE OF STOCKS PERFORMANCE BY MONTH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3566.png)
This is the link of the table I currently have, what i want is to multiply the fund value by the rows (months) end the result to multiply it by the following row and so on so I can have the value of the portfolio at the end of the year

I've tried

```
stock_variations$Month1 * funds
```

Also I've tried doing so individualy

```
funds <- 100000
a <- 1 + funds$*$Amazon$Month1
```

I've tried a lot of other things thet I found online, just can't find anything that works. Some results I get are **numeric(0)** and errors.

If someone knows it would be trully appreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: The picture of your data shows `df` but you reference `stock_variations` and `funds`, it's not at all clear what is what. I don't see how to multiple anything by a `Date` (which isn't a date, mind you, it's a row name, so it's `character`). However, one function you're likely looking for is `cumprod`, perhaps something like `lapply(df[c("AMAZON","APPLE","TESLA")], function(z) cumprod(1 + z))`.